# how to call a function on every open page using node.js vue.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

im new to websockets and for my project im using Socket.io.
what im trying to achive is having two taps and when a user clicks the button showDiv
the div will be displayd to all connected users. i do have connection with server and i can see if  a user is connected, but trying to implement my idea in vue is the hard stuff for me.

If you can help understand this i would appreciate it alot and thank you.

```js
new Vue({
el:'#wrapper',
data:{
    display: false,
    joined: false,
},
methods:{
     join() {
      this.joined = true;
      this.socketInstance = io("http://localhost:3000");
      this.socketInstance.on(
          "show", (data) => {
            this.display = this.display(data);
          }
      )
    },
     show(){
      const display = this.display
      if (display == false) {
        this.display = true
        this.socketInstance.emit('showDiv', display)
      }else {
        this.display= false
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.join();
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <h1 v-if="joined">We are connected</h1>
<h1 v-else>We are not connected</h1>

  <button @click="show">Show/hide Div</button>

  <div v-if="display" style="background-color: #4d00ff; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
  <div v-else>No div to see</div>
</div>
```

**Node.js server**

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ['GET', "POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`user ${socket.id} is connected.`)

    socket.on('message', data => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message:received', data)
    })

    socket.on('show', data =>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('showDiv',data)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`user ${socket.id} left.`)
    })
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App server is running on 3000')
})
```

Comment: You have not implemented the client-side of socket.io in your Vue app yet. Include the script and run `const socket = io();` and go from there.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention that in my question i already did that and i implemented like the following `import io from "socket.io-client";` and in the methods ```lang-js  methods: {
    displayDiv() {
      this.show = true;
      this.socketInstance = io("http://localhost:3000");
      this.socketInstance.on(
          "message:received", (data) => {
            this.messages = this.messages.concat(data);
          }
      )
    },}```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72100759/edit) the question instead of posting code in a comment. Also describe how the code fails, whether you're getting console errors and what you've attempted to fix it.

Comment: i edited the question and added the code that i was using to dispolay the div for all the pages

Comment: What is `this.display = this.display(data);` supposed to do? `this.display` is `false`, but you're calling it as a function. Also check your "show" and "showDiv" stuff. Both your client and server are *emitting* "showDiv" and *listening* for "show". And your vue app's show() function is a total mess.